# How to fetch customer account details from the already fetched acess_token of the user account for google analytics?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics-api

The user details are already fetched of the google account using the access token, but unable to fetch the customer accounts of that already logged-in google account.

Used google oauth2 for fetching the user details.

- Currently using nodejs.
- Imported Google api libraries.

Try:
Tried using the google ads api but was only able to retrieve the list of account ids of the customer(but needed all the details of the ad accounts).
Only customer account ids are getting retrieved.
Expecting:
All the details of the customer account ids.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include a link to the documentation you are following.   Example what api are you using exactly your code uses ads api yet you have tagged google analytics.   A link to the method you are calling would help as well.

Comment: Sorry @LindaLawton-DaImTo i posted the wrong code.
My only query is that, is there any api from where i can fetch the user's customer analytics account details using the access token.

Comment: Currently i am using these google-api libraries.

1. const { google } = require('googleapis');
2. const { GoogleAdsApi } = require('google-ads-api');

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. can you post a link to the documentation for the method you are trying to access.  Im still not sure if you are trying to access ads api or google analytics api can you fix our question and / or your tags.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, the thing is i have already fetched user details when account owner logs in.
Now, all i want is to fetch the owner's customer account details for both google ads and google analytics using access_token or something.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Sorry i am a newbie developer :), that's why i am unable to explain the problem properly.